# Wait until other users close the Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, tracker

I have created a 'Login Tracker' system where 100 people all use an excel form saved to their computer, and when they hit "submit" it opens another .xlsb file(RTS Report) in a shared drive, finds the next line, and puts the data on the next line. This all takes 2-5 seconds to complete, however, if two people hit "submit" at the same time then one gets an error that the file is already open.

im new in vba please help me code for following scenarios

1. Check if Database.xlsb is open by another user
2. If not, continue with the code
3. If yes (file is not available) code need wait for until file close

```vb
Sub RTS()

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ActiveSheet.Range("A7:D7", "Q7").Select
Range("Q7").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:="RTS Report.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False
Dim she As Worksheet

Dim a As Integer
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("data").Activate
Set she = actveworkbook.actvesheet

b = she.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

she.Range("A" & b + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, operation:=xlNone, Skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ThisWorkbook.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: imo: "Trackers" should be a database, not an Excel file. There are just too many problems with trying to share a file with that many people.

Comment: U mean ms access but we dont have access can u plse give me any exples links

Comment: no need to share a file jst Copy paste data Main workbook to another workbook 

my main workbook name is Login tracker so share this workbook to all users via mail
when end of the day  users clicking submit button na coping line form main workbook to another workbook (RTS Report). sometimes 2 users clicking same time na im getting error. please help me if any idea okey for me ( i dont have ms access)

Comment: It wouldn't have to be Access. You could use SQL Express (that's free) or MySQL (also free).

Comment: im working in TCS( tata consultancy services) they give application limited access only.

Comment: i n  ms office na ( excel, powerpoint, outlook) only installed. other apps not allowed :(

Comment: I just think with that many users, eventually someone is going to end up just saving it to their local drive instead of waiting and it will ruin the integrity of the data trying to sync them back up. Good Luck. :)

Comment: https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/copy-data-to-another-excel-workbook-based-on-criteria-using-vba/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, excel is not ideal for this, but if is the only thing you have the following should work.

try to open until error disappears

```
Sub RTS()

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ActiveSheet.Range("A7:D7", "Q7").Select
Range("Q7").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
cont = True

On Error Resume Next
While cont
    Err.Clear
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="RTS Report.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Err.Clear
    Else
        cont = False
    End If
Wend
On Error GoTo 0

Dim she As Worksheet

Dim a As Integer
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("data").Activate
Set she = actveworkbook.actvesheet

b = she.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

she.Range("A" & b + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, operation:=xlNone, Skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ThisWorkbook.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RTS()

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("GLOLOGIN")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Copy & Paste the data from " Scheduled Ad " sheet to "RTS Report.Xlsb" Sheet

ActiveSheet.Range("A7:D7", "Q7").Select
     ActiveSheet.Range("A7:D7,Q7").Select
    Range("Q7").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy


'RTS Report is not open then open the doc & pasete this data


cont = True

On Error Resume Next
While cont
    Err.Clear
Dim wb As Workbook


Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\PPR MUMBAI\Everythig Else\MIS\LILO\.Data\RTS Report.xlsx")

Do Until wb.ReadOnly = False
wb.Close

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\PPR MUMBAI\Everythig Else\MIS\LILO\.Data\RTS Report.xlsx")

Loop

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Err.Clear
    Else
        cont = False
    End If
    
Wend

On Error GoTo 0



Dim She As Worksheet
Dim b As Integer
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate
Set She = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

b = She.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

She.Range("A" & b + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

ThisWorkbook.Activate
 
ActiveSheet.Protect ("GLOLOGIN")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```